# How can I read tar.gz file using pandas read_csv with gzip compression option?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, gzip, tar

I have a very simple csv, with the following data, compressed inside the tar.gz file. I need to read that in dataframe using pandas.read_csv.

```
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("sample.tar.gz",compression='gzip')
```

However, I am getting error:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 440, saw 2
```

Following are the set of read_csv commands and the different errors I get with them:

```
pd.read_csv("sample.tar.gz",compression='gzip',  engine='python')
Error: line contains NULL byte

pd.read_csv("sample.tar.gz",compression='gzip', header=0)
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 440, saw 2

pd.read_csv("sample.tar.gz",compression='gzip', header=0, sep=" ")
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 94, saw 14    

pd.read_csv("sample.tar.gz",compression='gzip', header=0, sep=" ", engine='python')
Error: line contains NULL byte
```

What's going wrong here? How can I fix this?

Comment: `'.gz'` file is not same as `'.tar.gz'`

Comment: Ok, so what should I do to read the tar.gz file without unzipping it?

Comment: If it is a single file, why are you `tar`-ing it? Why not just `gzip` it? That way you can use pd.read_csv() on it directly.

Comment: I am not tar-ing it. It's given and I can't unzip the original file as it's more that 100 GB.

Comment: The actual file is here... https://ghtstorage.blob.core.windows.net/downloads/mysql-2016-07-19.tar.gz

Comment: @NehalJWani: Please advise!

Comment: If you manually unzip/untar and try to read the actual CSV file, does it work?

Comment: Yes, that works. But, I need to do it through Python program!

Comment: @Geet: No, I mean if you unzip/untar it and try to use `read_csv` on the actual CSV file, instead of trying to have pandas do the unzipping.

Comment: Yes, it worked with actual CSV file.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.tar.gz', compression='gzip', header=0, sep=' ', quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Note: `error_bad_lines=False` will ignore the offending rows.

Comment: Thanks, Marlon. What's ".dat" in 3rd line, here?

Comment: When I try that, it says, KeyError: "filename 'sample.dat' not found"

Comment: @Geet and also tell me your pandas version. This should work for  0.18.1

Comment: My pandas version is 0.18.1. The updated code give me "CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 440, saw 2" error

Comment: This worked for me for a sample csv file. your link let me download 40GB. don't you have a sample of it for me to test?

Comment: Check the code I set `error_bad_lines=False` and just now noticed your sep is an empty string. Can you try again with updated answer

Comment: Did it actually read all the data correctly?  Using `error_bad_lines` will just cause it to skip lines with errors, so the result may be missing some rows.  Those errors might indicate an actual error in the data file.

Comment: @BrenBarn: You are right, I see too many lines being skipped with that option. Any solution for that?

Comment: @Geet: I suspect there is some corruption in the file, but it could be hard to pinpoint it if the file is 40G.

Comment: I have tested with 2-3 much smaller tar.gz files, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: @Geet: It would be good if you could supply a reasonably-sized sample file (like a few KB) to test with.

Comment: @BrenBarn: I do have a 1-2 KB file, but how can I supply it here?

Comment: @Geet: You'll have to upload it somewhere and provide a link, as you did with your original file.

Comment: For pandas 2.0 it will be like:

```df = pd.read_csv(r"path_to_csv.gz_file",compression="gzip",header=0,sep=",",quotechar='"',on_bad_lines="skip")
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [`tarfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) to read a particular file from the tar.gz archive (as discussed in [this resolved issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16530#issuecomment-304684357)).
If there is only one file in the archive, then you can do this:

```
import tarfile
import pandas as pd
with tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz", "r:*") as tar:
    csv_path = tar.getnames()[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(tar.extractfile(csv_path), header=0, sep=" ")
```

The read mode `r:*` handles the gz extension (or other kinds of compression) appropriately.  If there are multiple files in the zipped tar file, then you could do something like `csv_path = list(n for n in tar.getnames() if n.endswith('.csv'))[-1]` line to get the last csv file in the archived folder.

Comment: Isn't `r:*` (or equivalently `r`) the default? I don't see what benefit it has to specify it explicitly.

Comment: @Asclepius explicit is better than implicit -zen of python

Comment: @tmthyjames Maybe you would like to program in C instead where everything is as explicit as it can be.

Comment: @Asclepius i can barely code in python! :)