# Unable to load data of the format .data using pandas into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data file, say  **"sample.data.gz"**, I have compressed it using gunzip to get **sample.data** file, but I'm unable to load it into pandas? I don't know how to load the data using .read_csv or .read_table.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @G.Anderson was trying to load it into pandas dataframe, using read_csv or read_table, I tried searching stackoverflow, but couldn't get anything.

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't clear. Please show some code for what you've tried, and what the result was, so we know specifically how to help. See this link on creating a [mcve]

Comment: @G.Anderson: I didn't get any result, my laptop just hanged, I had tried `df = pd.read_csv('sample.data')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-gz-pandas-tutorial) is a notebook labeld 'Quick .gz Pandas tutorial'. I think it might help.

On the other hand, if you have `.tar.gz`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263929/how-can-i-read-tar-gz-file-using-pandas-read-csv-with-gzip-compression-option).

Hope this helps!